# trying to get jenkins build of each job in jenkins

Tags: json

I am trying to get all the builds of a jenkins job though rest api GET `http://jenkins.yoursite.com/job/{job_name}/api/json/?tree=builds[url]&depth=3`,

I am getting the response as
`"_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject"`, I am unable to get the response as I want

Answer (score 0):

The `json` response from doing `curl http://jenkins.yoursite.com/job/{job_name}/api/json/` would give you all the API information you need from the job. You can use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) to filter what you get from the API.

I was able to query `builds` by `curl http://jenkins.yoursite.com/job/{job_name}/api/json/ | jq .r '.builds'`

Comment: In which format you are getting the builds (json or html). I want to get the builds information in json format.

Comment: Did you even try to look at `jq`? It is a command-line JSON processor.